# How do I correctly read a file byte by byte without losing any information

Tags: c, string, unicode, executable, binaryfiles

I guess the real goal is to successfully mimic strace's output in regards to the `read()` syscall argument reading that it magically outputs.

And to make this as clear as possible:

It means that it displays them in a way that WILL NOT be interpreted by the console.  For example, if a file contains \0004 or \0104 then it will DISPLAY \0004 and \0104 as LITERAL STRINGS (as if you wrote \\0004 or \\0104 instead) so it will NOT be interpreted by the console.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    #include <stdio.h>
    int shift(int times) {
        #ifdef SHIFT_VERBOSE
            int shift_mode_verbose = 1;
        #else
            int shift_mode_verbose = 0;
        #endif
        if (shift_mode_verbose == 1) {
            printf("The following arguments were passed (before) to main(%i):\n", argc);
            for(int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
                printf("arg%i: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        if (shift_mode_verbose == 1) {printf("shifting %i times\n", times);}
        for(int t=1; t<times+1; ++t) { // we set this to 1 and respectively increase by 1, to avoid shifting argv[0] as it is holds the program name
            for(int i=1; i<argc; ++i) { // we set this to 1 to avoid shifting argv[0] as it is holds the program name
                if (shift_mode_verbose == 1) {printf("shift %i: arg%i: %s >", t, i, argv[i]);}
                    argv[i]  = argv[i+1];
                if (shift_mode_verbose == 1) {printf(" %s\n", argv[i]);}
            }
            --argc;
        }
        if (shift_mode_verbose == 1) {
            printf("The following arguments were passed (after) to main(%i):\n", argc);
            for(int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
                printf("arg%i: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
        return 0;
    }

    int fshift(int times) { // a potentially faster version of shift()
        times = argc < times ? argc : times;
        argc = (argc) - times;
        (argv) += times;
        return 0;
    }
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s lines (-1 = all lines), files\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    int LINES_TO_READ = atoi(argv[1]);
    shift(1);
    for (ssize_t i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        const char *filename = argv[i];
        printf("printing \"%s\"\n\n", filename);        

        int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);

        if (fd < 0) {
            printf("cannot open \"%s\", returned %i\n", filename, fd);
            return -1;
        }

        char unsigned ch;
        size_t lines = 1;

        // Read the file byte by byte
        while (read(fd, &ch, 1) == 1) {
            if (ch == '\n') {
                printf("\\n");
            } else if (ch == '\0') {
                printf("\\0");
            } else if (ch == '\r') {
                printf("\\r");
            } else if (ch == '\t') {
                printf("\\t");
            } else if(isprint(ch)) {
                printf("%c", ch);
            } else {
                printf("\\%03o", ch);
            }
//         FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
//         char unsigned ch;
//         size_t lines = 1, bytes=1;
//         // Read the file byte by byte
//         while (fread(&ch, 1, 1, file) == 1) {
//             if (ch == '\n') {
//                 printf("\\n");
//             } else if (ch == '\0') {
//                 printf("\\0");
//             } else if (ch == '\r') {
//                 printf("\\r");
//             } else if (ch == '\t') {
//                 printf("\\t");
//             } else if(isprint(ch)) {
//                 printf("%c", ch);
//             } else {
//                 printf("\\%03o", ch);
//             }
            if (ch == '\n') {
                // Stop if we read 10 lines already
                if (lines == LINES_TO_READ) {
                    break;
                }
                lines++;
            }
        }

        if (close(fd) < 0) {
            printf("cannot close \"%s\"\n", filename);
            return -1;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Below is an example of what it should look like (apart from the `./catraw`'s output which is incorrect). (ELF header and instructions are acquired from `nasm`, `strace`, and c`at`.)

```
elf_header='\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\3\0\1\0\0\0T\200\4\0104\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0004\0 \0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\200\4\10\0\200\4\10T\0\0\0T\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\20\0\0'
instructions='\263*f1\300f@\315\200'
printf "$elf_header$instructions" > return_42
chmod +x return_42
./return_42 # test run to see if it actually works
echo $? # echo return code of ./return_42
strace -s 4096 cat ./return_42
gcc catraw.c --static -o catraw
strace ./catraw -1 ./return_42
./catraw -1 ./return_42

[PROGRAM ] \177ELF\001\001\001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\002\0\003\0\001\0\0\0T\200\004\0104\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\04\0 \0\001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\200\004\010\0\200\004\010T\0\0\0T\0\0\0\005\0\0\0\0\020\0\0\263*f1\300f@\315\200
```

Comment: The byte `'\177'` (decimal `127`) is *not* a Unicode character. It's just a byte without other meaning than being part of the ELF signature.

Comment: As for your problem and your question, can you please elaborate on the problem you have? What have you tried? How did your attempt work, or not work? What output do you get from your program, and what output did you expect? Please [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), then [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: iv tried this but with no luck https://bpaste.net/show/a6a0be8c56b9

Comment: put your code here, not on an external site

Comment: You can see from your first example `text='\177BYTE\0VAL\0T\200\0104\0\0\0004\0'` that there are several occurrences of `\0` so not all backslashes are followed by 3 octal digits.  It isn't entirely clear how the sequence `\0104\0\0\0004\0` should be translated. Is that `\0`, `1`, `0`, `4`, `\0`, `\0`, `\0`, `0`, `0`, `4`, `\0`, or `\010`, `4`, `\0`, `\0`, `\0`, `0`, `0`, `4`, `\0`, or something else?  A single 8-bit byte can hold values from `\000` to `\377`.

Comment: all \ byte sequences should be translates one character at a time if possible as if it where a literal array of bytes, \0104\0\0\0004\0 would be translated to \, 0, 1, 0, 4, \, 0, \, 0, \, 0, 0, 0, 4, \, 0 although bytes like \0104 may be translated as \0, 1, 0, 4, then have \0 translated to \\ 0 but i prefer then to be translates one character at a time to be avoid possible translation errors

Comment: Why do you want to write this program rather than use something  available?

Comment: is that better?

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever. `cat` doesn't interpret anything. It copies bytes. Your program does interpret bytes, but you state that the goal is to develop a program that does not. What is your *real* goal? If you want to show your input of *arbitrary bytes* as a stream of *printable characters*, there is a lot of programs out there that do that, no need to reinvent the wheel. Try `od -c`. Try to ask a different question, keeping it as focused as possible, as this one is't going to attract any attention.

Comment: @n.m. "the purpose is to impliment a RAW form of cat which will not interperate any back slashes at all and preserve all formatting" means that it displays them in a way that WILL NOT be interpreted by the console

Comment: You want a program that **converts** non-printable characters to some kind of printable representation. Not a "raw form of cat" which doesn't make any sense. Cat doesn't cook anything. There is nothing more raw than cat.

Comment: Incidentally, you are not supposed to include standard headers inside the scope of a function.  Also, in standard C, you can't nest functions; GCC has an extension that allows that, but I wouldn't recommend exploiting that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit unclear (not sure about all the assembly), but something like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>

// Format the character 'c' (which should be cast from char) into a 
// string. Will use backslash-escaped form for non-printables.
void tostring(char *buf, size_t buf_max, unsigned int c)
{
  if(isprint(c))
  {
    snprintf(buf, buf_max, "%c", c);
  }
  else
  {
    snprintf(buf, buf_max, "\\%3o", c);
  }
}
```

This builds `"\177"` when called with `c = 0177`.

And yes, obviously the call to `snprintf()` in the first case can be factored out for printables.

Comment: The first case should presumably test for `\\`...

Comment: how is "isprint" different from the other "is's" iv tried? and yay it works

Comment: @ClarkKent That's a bit hard to answer ... it's different from `isascii()` which I found in your pastebinned code, since it checks for any printable character, where `isascii()` of course only checks for 7-bit ASCII printables.

Comment: although it does seem to produce a slightly different output:\0004 (as strace) vs \04 (as urs), read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\3\0\1\0\0\0T\200\4\0104\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0004\0 \0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\200\4\10\0\200\4\10[\0\0\0[\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\263*1\300@\315\200", 131072) = 91                                                                                       $ ct ./t
\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\3\0\1\0\0\0T\200\4\104\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\04\0 \0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\200\4\10\0\200\4\10[\0\0\0[\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\263*1\300@\315\200

Comment: 0T\200\4\0104‌​\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0‌​\0004   and 0T\200\4\104\0‌​\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0‌​4, also \104 instead of strace \0104

Comment: in wich results in printf "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\3\0\1\0\0\0T\200\4\104\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\04\0 \0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\200\4\10\0\200\4\10[\0\0\0[\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\263*1\300@\315\200" > test3 ; chmod +x test3 ; ./test3 ; echo $?
bash: ./test3: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: @ClarkKent The shell's `printf` is only going to parse up to three octal digits, so `\0004` means the two bytes 0 and 52, while `\04` is just the single byte 4. This can be confusing.

Comment: ok, is there any way to work around this?

Comment: read(3, "\0", 1)
read(3, "T", 1) 
read(3, "\200", 1)
read(3, "\4", 1)
read(3, "\10", 1)
read(3, "4", 1) 
read(3, "\0", 1)
read(3, "\0", 1)
read(3, "\0", 1)
read(3, "\0", 1)
read(3, "\0", 1)
read(3, "\0", 1)
read(3, "\0", 1)
read(3, "\0", 1)
read(3, "\0", 1)
read(3, "\0", 1)
read(3, "\0", 1)
read(3, "4", 1) // \0T\200\4\0104‌​\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0‌​\0004\0 \0
read(3, "\0", 1)
read(3, " ", 1) 
read(3, "\0", 1)

Comment: the problem might be with read() itself...

Comment: @ClarkKent I'm sorry, you've lost me. Obviously the standard `read()` function is not broken ...

Comment: this is the correct way to read a file byte by byte right? const char *filename = argv[i]; int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY); while (read(fd, &ch, 1) != 0) {

Comment: @ClarkKent Please post a new question, trying hard to keep it as small and clear as possible; this question is put on hold.

Comment: if i set the bytes to read to 16 it appears to read correctly... (but i get a broken read followed by a read(0 then a segv))   read(3, "\2\0\3\0\1\0\0\0T\200\4\0104\0\0\0", 16) = 16
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0004\0 \0\1\0\0\0", 16) = 16

Comment: You probably want `"\\%03o"` format, and also you want to escape the literal backslash.

Comment: @n.m. ok, welp it half works and it half doesnt xP

Comment: [mine] \177ELF\001\001\001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\002\0\003\0\001\0\0\0T\200\004\0104\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\04\0 \0\001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\200\004\010\0\200\004\010T\0\0\0T\0\0\0\005\0\0\0\0\020\0\0\263*f1\300f@\315\200

Comment: [strace] \177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\3\0\1\0\0\0T\200\4\0104\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0004\0 \0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\200\4\10\0\200\4\10T\0\0\0T\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\263*f1\300f@\315\200

Comment: @ClarkKent If you want to mimic `strace` exactly, why not look at its source code? (And why mimic `strace` exactly, is it some kind of holy scripture?)

Comment: @ClarkKent anyway your question is closed, you are not going to get any new answers. If you want answers, you need to ask another question.